# h:inputtext not working with multiple forms in JSF2.2

Tags: jsf-2.2

h:inputText is not working in the latest JSF2.2 with multiple forms.
I have 2 forms

form1 have:
 one command button and one input text

form2 has:
one input text and one output label

on click of command button in form1, i am rendering the form2(both outputlabel and input text).

but only output label is rendered properly with correct values (corresponding getter method gets called and value is displaying) but the input text is not calling the corresponding getter method hence showing null.

Note:
we noticed this issue only if we use multiple forms, within single form its working fine.
also it worked fine in JSF2.0

Version used:
JSF api - 2.2 (com.sun.faces)
JSF impl - 2.2 (com.sun.faces)

let me know if anyone have solution to handle this.

the forms are not nested and both the beans are in View scope.

```
<h:form id="form1">
<a4j:commandLink id="actionEdit" title="Click" action="#{bean.action}" 
render="paymentInstructionDetail" styleClass="iconLarge edit" />
</h:form>


<h:form id="form2">
  <a4j:outputPanel ajaxRendered="true" id="paymentInstructionDetail">
     <h:inputText value="#{bean1.amount}" id="sample"/>
     <h:outputLabel value="#{bean1.amount}" id="sampleLabel"/>
 </a4j:outputPanel>
</h:form>
```

after the action is completed in form1, the form2 outputlabel is displaying the value properly(getter method is called) but the inputtext is not displaying the value (getter method is not getting called)

Hi john, to test whether the above issue is working fine without richfaces, i created a standalone project and create a xhtml as below

```
<h:body>
    <h2>This is start.xhtml</h2>
    <h:form>
        <h:commandButton action="#{myBean.testAction}" value="Payment" >
            <f:ajax render="sample"></f:ajax>
        </h:commandButton>
    </h:form>
    <h:form id="test12" prependId="false">
        <h:inputText value="#{myBean.orderQty}" id="sample"/>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

but i am getting unknown id for sample, is there any way to check with multiple forms?

Comment: Are the two forms nested? What is the bean scope? Note that you can only 'render' outside a form, you cannot 'process' outside a form. A code snippet could help ;)

Comment: hi john, i have updated the details in the above query

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with richfaces (a4j), but try the following:

-If you don't use `form prependId=false`, then you should refer to your (other form) id's as: `render=":form2:paymentInstructionDetail" styleClass="iconLarge edit" />`

On another note:
-I don't think that richfaces is JSF2.2 ready yet, so expect problems
-Actually, JSF 2.2 has quite a few bugs of it's own

Comment: Hi John, i checked with standalone application without richfaces, but facing an error. i have updated the above post with details. let me know if i am missing something.

Comment: Did you try updating the render attribute to `render=":form2:paymentInstructionDetail"` without removing richfaces?

Comment: i used the second example given in the above post and not the first one. there i used render="sample"

Comment: try render=":sample". Since you are reffering to sample from within the a form it will look into that scope.

Comment: i tried ':sample' but still the issue persists. Is JSF2.2 stable enough to migrate?

Comment: In my opinion JSF 2.2 is not yet stable for you to migrate. Regarding your problem you should use the full component it, so the code that you have above should be `render=":sample"` or `render=":test12:sample"` if you prepend ids . If you use plain JSF, this should work.

Comment: Just to provide some further insights. You have set the second form with `prependid=false`. This should create components without the formId. But, you are reffering to it from another form that doesn't have prependid=false. As far as I know, providing an id withou `:` will look for this component inside the first form context.