# JSF tag is not working on *.xhtml but working *.jsp file

Tags: jsf, facelets, jsf-2.2, glassfish-2.x

I am trying to run simple application using JSF 2.2, Netbeans 7.3 and GlassFish v2.

`index.xhtml`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
   xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
       <b>Hello from Facelets</b>
       <h:form id="this">
           <h:outputText value="This is"/>
       </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

`web.xml`:

```
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>  
</web-app>
```

Output:

---

[image: Output file]

---

The `<b>Hello from Facelets</b>` is working but `<h:outputText value="this is "/>` is not working. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

I searched here and found the following questions:

- [JSF Form is not showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002047/jsf-form-is-not-showing-up)
- [h:inputtext not working with multiple forms in JSF2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17424292/hinputtext-not-working-with-multiple-forms-in-jsf2-2)

However, the answers did not solve myproblem.

---

**Update**: @Xtreme Biker, when I changed like you said I got following exception:

[image: This is exception]

**Note:** If I used `*.jsp` instead of `*.xhtml` it works. But when I make my `index` file extension `xhtml` it is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using GlassFish v2, which is an ancient Java EE 5 container which already bundles JSF 1.2. The webapp-supplied JSF is by default **ignored** and essentially, you're running JSF 1.2 all the time. That explains why JSP works fine. Facelets is only supported since JSF 2.0.

You have the following options, depending on whether your requirement is being able to use JSF 2.2, or being restricted to GlassFish v2:

1. If you're restricted to GlassFish v2, then you can't use JSF 2.2 at all. JSF 2.2 requires a minimum of Java EE 6 (GlassFish 3). You can however use JSF 2.0 or 2.1. You can download latest JSF 2.1 from [here](http://javaserverfaces.java.net) (currently, 2.1.25). Drop the `javax.faces.jar` in `/WEB-INF/lib` and edit the `/WEB-INF/sun-web.xml` to add the following entries to `<sun-web-app>`:

   ```
   <class-loader delegate="false"/> 
   <property name="useBundledJsf" value="true" />
   ```

   This will basically instruct GlassFish to prefer webapp-bundled JSF over its own bundled JSF.

   ---
2. If you're not restricted to GlassFish v2 and can upgrade it, then do it as soon as possible. GlassFish v2 is an ancient container from May 2006 and succeeded by GlassFish 3 (Java EE 6) in Dec 2009 which is in turn succeeded by GlassFish 4 (Java EE 7) in May 2013.

   GlassFish 3.0 bundles JSF 2.0 and GlassFish 3.1 bundles JSF 2.1. But both are upgradeable to JSF 2.2 the same way as GlassFish v2 with the difference that `sun-web.xml` has been renamed to `glassfish-web.xml`. Another way is simply replacing the `jsf-api.jar`+`jsf-impl.jar` or `javax.faces.jar` in GlassFish's `/modules` directory by the desired version.

   GlassFish 4.0 bundles JSF 2.2 and you don't need to manually supply any JARs. I would currently however not recommend using GlassFish 4.0. It's too buggy (like as every first major release of GlassFish). Better wait for 4.0.1 (if it ever comes out) or a 4.1.

   ---
3. If you're restricted to GlassFish v2 and can't upgrade to JSF 2.x somehow, but you really, really want to use Facelets, then you can always install Facelets 1.x separately. The procedure is described in [this docbook](http://facelets.java.net/nonav/docs/dev/docbook.html). However, whilst you've got the advantages of using Facelets instead of JSP, sticking to JSF 1.x is [disavantageous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623911/what-are-the-main-disadvantages-of-java-server-faces-2-0/3646940#3646940). I really wouldn't recommend that.

Answer (score 4):

Change your servlet mapping in order to work with **.xhtml** files. It seems not to be yet converting the tags.

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: But I got exception please see my edited question I am showing exception.

Comment: Apparently your welcome file is not being catched. Change from `faces/index.xhtml` to just `index.xhtml`.

Comment: Yes, when I replaced code that you provided. After that I had alrady changed `faces/index.xhtml` to just `index.xhtml`.

Comment: Do you have JSF required jars properly deployed in your server? That implies JSF-api and also a JSF implementation (Mojarra, MyFaces). Are you using Maven?

Comment: I am not using maven. I used jar which is provided by Netbeans IDE

Comment: Then check wherever Netbeans is deploying your server stuff that you've them in your classpath (WEB-INF dir).

Comment: Everything is done. But something is wrong. Where I am not finding that issue. If you do not mind and is it possible can you try yourself. Please.......

Comment: I suppose when you say `<h:outputText value="this is "/> is not working` that you're seeing the tag itself in your browser? What's your output? Sorry but I can't try it myself without installing your whole enviroment.

Comment: Ok sir thank you. I am just saying only to try `if it is possible`. But it is confusing me if I used `.jsp` works but not `.xhtml` .

Answer (score 2):

Try to replace this,

```
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
```

instead of

```
 xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
```

Comment: I did but nothing happen

Comment: can you post your full index.xhtml file

Comment: @Kalathoki Did you republish/rebuild/restart your server? Which error do you get?

Comment: @noone yes sir. I restart my glassfish server and also netbeans and also closed my browser.

Comment: @noone Sir I did not get error but `<h:outputText value="this is "/>` code is not working. Thats all. Please see my output. Which was displayed  When I run my application.